# Hosted exchange Migration to Office 365

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, hosted

I received a new task from our company and it is about the email migration from the hosted exchange to Office 365

I prefer to use cutover migration methode

https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/Exchange/mailbox-migration/cutover-migration-to-office-365?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fCutover-migration-to-Office-365-9496e93c-1e59-41a8-9bb3-6e8df0cd81b4#ID0EAABAAA=Run_a_cutover_migration

however this migration manual requires the access to the exchange admin center in order to create the migration endpoint!

The hoster doesn't allow the access to their exchange, but I can access the management portal for the hosted mail service. this management portal provides limited services without no reference to the migration.

Is there anyone who has the similiar situation and migrated the mail with cutover sucessfully?

I do appreciate for every answer and suggestion.

Best Regards
Tommy

Comment: Time to talk to your hosting provider, methinks.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyone who has the similar situation and migrated the mail
>   with cutover sucessfully?

It's obvious that if you can't create the migration endpoints then you can't perform a cutover migration.

Furthermore, how could anyone have been successful if they weren't able to create the migration endpoints?

If you can't create migration endpoints then you can't use any migration method that requires migration endpoints.

Your question should be "How can I migrate my email from hosted Exchange to Office 365 without using migration endpoints?"

Comment: Hallo, yes, you are right. I should have asked the same question. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think you'll need to look into an IMAP migration or exporting/importing PST files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The only way is let end users to migrate their data via Export/Import pst files in outlook.